# Process a list of tasks asynchronously using Task.WhenAny

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I create a list of tasks. As soon as some task in the list completes, I want to process its result (in this case, print the name of a blob).

The code (contained within an async function) reads as follows:

```
List<Task<BlobResultSegment>> taskList = new List<Task<BlobResultSegment>>();
BlobContinuationToken token = null;
do
{
    taskList.Add(blobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(token));
}
while (token != null);
            
while(taskList.Any())
{
    Task<BlobResultSegment> completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskList);
    await completedTask.ContinueWith(task => {
        foreach (IListBlobItem item in task.Result.Results)
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = item as CloudBlockBlob;
            Console.WriteLine(blob.Name); // this statement causes the error
        }
    });
    taskList.Remove(completedTask);
}
```

The error that is produced:
*'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*

Why is the error produced and how can I fix it?

The task specified in the `ContinueWith` method should be executed after the preceding task has finished, so I do not understand what the problem is.

As a side note, the code runs if the statement containing the `WriteLine` method is removed.

Comment: Very likely, item is not a CloudBlockBlob object. It could even be null. It depends on BlobResultSegment.Results implementation.

Comment: Well you've not told the line where this occurs. The code you posted has multiple points where a null reference exception can occur. `task.Result.Results` if `task.Result` is `null` this will throw the mentioned error. `item as CloudBlockBlob` this will return `null` if `item` is not of type `CloudBlockBlob` if that happens the next line `blob.Name` will throw the mentioned error.

Comment: Why are you even using `ContinueWith` here? It shouldn't be related to the error, but you are just making your logic more complicated that way. You have already awaited the task, just add the code you need below it and it will happen after the task has completed as well.

The problem you are seeing is, as @Rubidium37 said, probably due to the `as` cast. You should _never_ use `as` and then "assume" it is that type, since `as` can return null. Use a normal cast instead if you are sure that the object must be of the given type, or handle the case where it could be another type.

Comment: Out of curiosity, your code implies that you want to run all the tasks concurrently, and all their continuations sequentially (one continuation after the other, without overlapping). Is this intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ContinueWith`; it's a dangerous, low-level method.

Also, I strongly recommend against the "`WhenAny` then remove it from the list" approach. It's almost an antipattern. The code is much simpler if you introduce a helper asynchronous method instead.

On to the Azure-specific problems. First, the way `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` works is that you need to call it one at a time, updating the token with the result of each call, like this:

```
List<IListBlobItem> blobs = new();
BlobContinuationToken token = null;
do
{
  var result = await blobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(token);
  blobs.AddRange(result.Results);
  token = result.ContinuationToken;
} while (token != null);

foreach (var item in blobs)
{
  CloudBlockBlob blob = item as CloudBlockBlob;
  Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
}
```

As for the null reference exception, it's most likely because there's a blob that isn't a `CloudBlockBlob`, e.g., `CloudBlobDirectory`. I'd recommend something like this:

```
foreach (var item in blobs)
{
  if (item is CloudBlob blob)
    Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
  else if (item is CloudBlobDirectory dir)
    Console.WriteLine("Dir: " + dir.Prefix);
}
```